# Error when retrieving icons from other Android packages

Tags: android, delphi

I am receiving an exception when retrieving the icon of other installed packages.  The point of failure is indicated in the code below (The getBitmap function of TJBitmapDrawable).  The error message is:

> Project ....apk raised exception class Aborted (6).

However, the code does work for retrieving its own package icon, i.e., passing in the package name of the application that the code is executing within works just fine.

```
procedure TViewModelFormMain.GetPackageIcon(const PackageName: string; Bitmap: TBitmap);
var joDrawable: JDrawable;
    p: Pointer;
    joBitmapDrawable: JBitmapDrawable;
    joBitmap: JBitmap;
    Surface: TBitmapSurface;
    appInfo: JApplicationInfo;
begin
  appInfo := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(StringToJString(PackageName), 0);
  if not Assigned(appInfo) then
    Exit;

  joDrawable := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
  if not Assigned(joDrawable) then
    Exit;

  p := (joDrawable as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;
  if not Assigned(p) then
    Exit;

  joBitmapDrawable := TJBitmapDrawable.Wrap(p);
  if not Assigned(joBitmapDrawable) then
    Exit;

  joBitmap := joBitmapDrawable.getBitmap;  // Fails here
  if not Assigned(joBitmap) then
    Exit;

  Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    if JBitmapToSurface(joBitmap, Surface) then
      Bitmap.Assign(Surface);
  finally
    Surface.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The application is targeting Android 9 (API 28).  Same results and error when using either Delphi XE 10.4.2 or Delphi XE 11 (Update 1).  The application has been granted both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.

Any suggestions or advice?  Are there other permissions needed?

** Update 2022-03-01 **
I've added a request for the 'android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES', though, if I understand the documentation correctly, it is new with API 30.  Regardless, I still receive the same error as before.

Also, below I've included all the code from a simple test project that will give a fuller context.

Any suggestions or advice would be most welcome.

```
unit FormMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants
  , System.Permissions, FMX.DialogService, FMX.Surfaces, FMX.Helpers.Android
  , FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ListView
  , FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base
  , Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.Jni.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText
  , Androidapi.Jni.Os, Androidapi.JNIBridge
  ;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPermissionExternalRead: string;
    FPermissionExternalWrite: string;
    FPermissionQueryAllPackages: string;
    procedure GetPackageIcon(const AppInfo: JApplicationInfo; Bitmap: TBitmap);
    procedure LoadPackages;
    procedure PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPermissionExternalRead := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  FPermissionExternalWrite := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  FPermissionQueryAllPackages := 'android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES';
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(  [FPermissionExternalRead
                                          , FPermissionExternalWrite
                                          , FPermissionQueryAllPackages]
                                          , PermissionRequestResult
                                          , nil);
  ListView1.ItemAppearanceName := 'ImageListItem';
  LoadPackages;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.GetPackageIcon(const AppInfo: JApplicationInfo; Bitmap: TBitmap);
var joDrawable: JDrawable;
    p: Pointer;
    joBitmapDrawable: JBitmapDrawable;
    joBitmap: JBitmap;
    Surface: TBitmapSurface;
begin
//  joDrawable := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
  joDrawable := AppInfo.loadIcon(TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageManager);
  if not Assigned(joDrawable) then
    Exit;

  p := (joDrawable as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;
  if not Assigned(p) then
    Exit;

  joBitmapDrawable := TJBitmapDrawable.Wrap(p);
  if not Assigned(joBitmapDrawable) then
    Exit;

  joBitmap := joBitmapDrawable.getBitmap;  // Fails here
  if not Assigned(joBitmap) then
    Exit;

  Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    if JBitmapToSurface(joBitmap, Surface) then
      Bitmap.Assign(Surface);
  finally
    Surface.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.LoadPackages;
var PkgList : JList;
    Intent : JIntent;
    i: Integer;
    ResolveInfo : JResolveInfo;
    ActivityInfo : JActivityInfo;
    AppInfo : JApplicationInfo;
    lvItem : TListViewItem;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
  Intent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

  PkgList := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, 0);
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to PkgList.size - 1 do
    begin
      ResolveInfo := TJResolveInfo.Wrap((PkgList.get(i) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
      ActivityInfo := TJActivityInfo.Wrap((ResolveInfo.activityInfo as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
      AppInfo := TJApplicationInfo.Wrap((ActivityInfo.applicationInfo as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

      lvItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      lvItem.Text := JStringToString(AppInfo.packageName);

      if PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted(FPermissionQueryAllPackages) or
         (lvItem.Text = 'com.embarcadero.SimplePackageList') then
      begin
        GetPackageIcon(AppInfo, lvItem.Bitmap);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
begin
  if not (Length(AGrantResults) >= 2) and
                (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
                (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
  begin
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Cannot import/export menu items, because the required permissions are not all granted');
  end;

  if not (Length(AGrantResults) >= 3) and
                (AGrantResults[2] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
  begin
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Cannot query package icons, because the required permissions are not all granted');
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t do exactly same test, coz got only Delphi 11 with default SDK/NDK settings, but your functions works well with another apps after adding “Query all packages” permission. Test Phone – android 11.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this issue.  I added "Query all packages" permission, but still no change in behavior.  I must be missing something more.  I may soon edit the original post to include all the code of the project.  Perhaps, that shed some more light on the issue.  Thanks, again, for the advice.